# get order address when sending invoice

Tags: php, magento

I'm overriding the `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template`-class `send()`-method in order to send an SMS to the customer at the same time as the email is being sent.
What I'm not sure how to do is to get the customer information connected to the order. Usally all the information is inserted in the email template as variables, but I need to access it in PHP from the mentioned class. And it needs to be the customer information, like name, phone and so on from the order object since orders may be placed without registering on the webshop (also to get the correct phonenumber for the specific order).

Any help would be highly appreciated, I have no idea how to even get the orderId from within this class.  Also would like to be able to list these customer specific field-names in an admin-view for choosing the telephone field as the source of SMS recipient, so if there's a way to output all the customer specific field-names connected to orders that would be great too.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I've seen an SMS module that works much in the same way, and that seems to just load the information with: `$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();`and then later `$billing = $customer->getDefaultBilling();`- I'll see if I can get that to work - but it doesn't feel like it should.. unless the email class loads current customer to session/customer before sending the mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still say that event-capture is the practical way, but I respect your point of view. So in the other way, the `sendMail` method of `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invice` contains the "order" object as template parameter:

```
       $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'order'        => $order,
            'invoice'      => $this,
            'comment'      => $comment,
            'billing'      => $order->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
        )
    );
```

The `mailer` object is an instance of `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer` class, i recommend to overwrite the `send` method of this class, and then you can access the data you need via method `$this->getTemplateParams()`, and the address and customer information from the order object, as you can find in my previous answer.

Comment: This really helped! `$this-getTemplateParams()` wasn't accessible inside the `send()` function, but it did already have the same information passed to it in the form of an array called `variables` that I never looked at before. That array seems to contain all the objects and data I need - so thanks for leading me in the right direction by telling me that the template data is passed on.

Answer (score 1):

Magento has an event-driven architecture, so in issues like this it is much better to create an Observer to catch an event. [How to create observers](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) This event in your case is "sales_order_invoice_register". For this you need in your module's config eg. `app/code/local/Stack/Test/etc/config.xml`:

```
        <events>
        <sales_order_invoice_register>
            <observers>
                <stacktest>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>stacktest/observer</class>
                    <method>sendSMS</method>
                </stacktest>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_invoice_register>
    </events>
```

And in you Observer, which is `app/code/local/Stack/Test/Model/Observer.php`:

```
class Stack_Test_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Observer
{
public function sendSMS($observer)
{
    #get the customer
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

    Mage::log($order->getBillingAddress());
    Mage::log($order->getShippingAddress())
    Mage::log($order->getCustomerEmail());
    Mage::log($order->getCustomerFirstname());
    Mage::log($order->getCustomerLastname());
    ...
```

You can get all data like this, and send the sms directly from the Observer class, no need to override the `send` method.

Comment: Please note that the code samples above are not the whole files, only parts of them as examples.

Comment: As I said, I'm not sure this is practical since I need this on every email sent.

Comment: In the title you wrote "when sending invoice". If you need sms sending on invoice create, this is the most practical way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are overriding the `send` function you can use its parameter `$variables`, an array, which contains, among other data, an `order` object (`$variables['order']`). This is true for the order email, invoice, shipment, and creditmemo emails.

This make my suggestion of "registering an order" redundant.

---

The first thing that comes to mind is to capture an event dispatched when an order is placed and save the order object from the event into the Magento registry. Then you can fetch that registry entry from your overridden `send` function. This should work assuming the SMS is sent during the request that submits the order, and not later, like when the SMS are dispatched from a queue processor.

So this idea can be implemented like this:

Register the observer

```
<config>
    <!-- -->
    <global>
        <!-- -->
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <yournodename>
                        <class>YourPackage_YourModule_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>registerOrder</method>
                    </yournodename>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
        <!-- -->
    </global>
    <!-- -->
</config>
```

Implement the observer

```
class YourPackage_YourModule_Model_Observer 
{
    public function registerOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        Mage::register('currentOrder', $order);
    }
}
```

Access the registry entry:

```
public function send()
    {
        $order = Mage::registry('currentOrder');
        if ($order instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order) {
            $address = $order->getBillingAddress();
            if (!$order->getCustomerId()) {
                //guest order
            } else  {
                $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                    ->load($order->getCustomerId());
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi and thank you, but this is not just for when placing an order, this should be connected to every email.